# How to ignore char sequence in filter?

Tags: java, android, filter

How to ignore char sequence in filter? I want to put some values, but no matter of their order and get results with them.

```
    @Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
    FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
    if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
        ArrayList<Country> filteredItems = new ArrayList<Country>();

        for(int i = 0, l = originalList.size(); i < l; i++) {
            Country country = originalList.get(i);

            if(constraint.toString().toLowerCase().contains(
                        country.getRegion().toString().toLowerCase()))
                filteredItems.add(country);
        }
        result.count = filteredItems.size();
        result.values = filteredItems;
    } else {
        synchronized(this) {
            result.values = originalList;
            result.count = originalList.size();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: char sequence?  what sequence?

Comment: For example I've got Region with "reg1, reg2, reg3" and Region with "reg1, reg3" and if I put values like "reg1, reg2, reg3" it will only show me this values, but I want both of Regions to be shown.

Comment: sorry,  still unclear to me

Comment: your question is not clear? kindly give a brief explanation?

Comment: I'm using this code http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-custom-layout-filter.html but I want to add more values in Region and filter them no matter of putted order in EditText

Comment: Here's my explantation, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279281/how-to-filter-listview-with-few-values?noredirect=1#comment48657023_30279281