# How to filter listview with few values?

Tags: java, android, filter

I want to get items with values which I typed, but it doesn't work right.

To understand my problem I'll show it by example.

what I want to get (if exists in listview) is:

```
Input: Africa, Asia, Europe 
Output: 
Reg1: Africa
Reg2: Europe
Reg3: Asia
Reg4: Asia, Africa
Reg5: Africa, Europe
Reg6: Asia, Europe
Reg7: Africa, Asia, Europe
```

what I really get is(not good):

```
Input: Africa, Asia, Europe
Output:
Reg7: Africa, Asia, Europe
```

or (not good too)

```
Input: Africa
Output:
Reg4: Asia, Africa
Reg5: Africa, Europe
Reg7: Africa, Asia, Europe
```

Here's my filter...

```
    @Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
    FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
    if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
        ArrayList<Country> filteredItems = new ArrayList<Country>();

        for(int i = 0, l = originalList.size(); i < l; i++) {
            Country country = originalList.get(i);

            if(country.getRegion().toString().toLowerCase().contains(
                        constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                filteredItems.add(country);
        }
        result.count = filteredItems.size();
        result.values = filteredItems;
    } else {
        synchronized(this) {
            result.values = originalList;
            result.count = originalList.size();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why are the outputs wrong ? In each case you only get rows that contain the input words ? That is exactly what you state what you wanted ?  Ha ! I see. You want an 'or' not an 'and'.

Comment: Yes, but everything which would be shown must be typed, because I don't want to get values like in 3rd example.